# Shell Job Control: Track status of background with WNOHANG wait

Tags: shell, wait, background-process

What does GNU mean by this line (from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stopped-and-Terminated-Jobs.html))?

> The shell must also check on the status of background jobs so that it can report terminated and stopped jobs to the user; this can be done by calling waitpid with the `WNOHANG` option.

I don't understand why the shell should alert the user about background processes before executing. What would that look like too? Like, call ls, but a background process completed, so that process' status is printed before ls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for implementing notifications like the following for background jobs:

```
$ cmd_1 &
$ cmd_2
$ cmd_3
[1]+  Done                    cmd_1
$
```

(Something like `sleep 5` is a good `cmd_1` to try this out with.)

In the above, it's assumed that the backgrounded `cmd_1` job finishes while `cmd_3` is being typed in or run. The notification is delivered afterwards, just before printing the last prompt above.

`waitpid(2)` is used to wait for processes to change state (either terminate or stop or start, as in what e.g. `Ctrl-Z` and `fg` does).

To implement the display above, the shell can call `waitpid(2)` to check if the background job has changed state each time before prompting for a new command. If it does this without passing `WNOHANG`, then the `waitpid()` call will block until the background job actually changes state, meaning the shell will be stuck until `cmd_1` finishes before printing the second prompt. `WNOHANG` makes the `waitpid()` call non-blocking and allows the shell to "poll" for state changes in the job instead.

Comment: When you say "just before printing the last prompt above", do you mean after any output of cmd_3?

Comment: @Fire3galaxy: Yup, exactly. The output of `cmd_3` would appear before the notification.